# How to update an open file which is modified in java?

Tags: java, file, file-handling

I'm working on a Speech to Text Project where I'm supposed to make a text editor which types when someone speaks. What I have done is when someone speaks it gets appended to the file with the use of

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\voice_type_test.txt");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
writer.append("Text to be appended.");
writer.close();
```

**Problem Statement:** The file gets modified **perfectly** but it wouldn't update the open window and it's content. That's obvious! I want a way so that it would also update the open .txt file. Because reading a file every time a new line is added is not a viable option!

**Example**

**File content is: (both in open text editor and in the file on hard disk)**

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO

**File content after the modification:**

**(on hard disk)**

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
Text to be appended.

**(on screen editor)**

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO

[edit]

**Update:** Screen-editor/Text Editor refers to any text editor whether it is Notepad, WordPad, Word, Eclipse's code area etc.

Comment: what is  screen editor? editor of yours ? you need to create a simple editor or you need to close and reopen the window

Comment: You can think of it as a notepad window.

Comment: @FastSnail Actually it's meant to work in any text editor...whether it's notepad, wordpad, eclipse's code area....

Comment: This will only work if editor supports detection of changes to underling file, so eclipse maybe, but not notepad and wordpad...

Comment: @Adam Can you elaborate how to update changes in Eclipse. That would also be helpful to me....Maybe some Change Listener ??

Comment: What if you display the text in a jframe so you don't have to worry about updating the text editor? Or close/reopen that file .

Comment: u can use real time text editor .for example notepad++ https://www.raymond.cc/blog/monitor-log-or-text-file-changes-in-real-time-with-notepad/

Comment: You can also re-load the editor window. Thats how most editors work anyway

Comment: @SaifAsif I have thought about it...but I felt that it's an expensive operation and it might create lags if the file is big!

Comment: @AndrewV I appreciate your idea but this Speech to Text Project is meant to be an assistance for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. consider using java.awt.Robot. This will send input to the current window with focus, so should work with anything.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(1000);
String helloWorld = "Hello world";
for (char c : helloWorld.toCharArray()) {

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }
    robot.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    robot.keyRelease(Character.toUpperCase(c));

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not automatically update content in the text editor which is the main requirement I guess. It will only make the editor in the front of the screen right ?

Comment: Can you explain what is going on inside the `for each` loop ?

Comment: The current requirement to update ANY editor including notepad etc. cannot be met so just offering an alternative.

Comment: @sidkamaria It sends the string character by character as if the user had typed it on the keyboard.